# Switching axis in R histogram

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2, visualization

How should I switch X and Y axis in histograms?:

```
hist(Minimum)
```

Also, I wanted to have the X-axis range from 0 to 30. 
I am very new to R programming, any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use the output of `hist` to then construct a horizontal barplot. See `?hist`

Comment: To expand: `figs <- hist(Minimum); barplot(figs$counts,horiz=TRUE);`

Comment: function [hist](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html) is from the base graphics but your question is marked with ggplot. My answer below is applicable to latter only.

Answer (score 3):

Use function [coord_flip](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/coord_flip.html) added to your ggplot histogram:

```
plot = ggplot(...) + ...

plot + coord_flip()
```